# Why isn't await working with async on firefox

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

basically i have this function

```
async function get(url){
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const resData = await response.text();
  return resData;
}
```

then later i have this call

```
let data = await get(am_url);
```

the code works perfectly on google chrome, but on firefox, i get this error on the call line :

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators

what's the problem here, for the life of me, i can't seem to make this work on firefox and can't figure out why

for example if i open google.com on firefox and google chrome, then i go to the console, and pase this code, on chrome, it will run, but on firefox, it will throw the error i mentionned

```
async function get(url){
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const resData = await response.text();
  return resData;
}

let data = await get("http://google.com");
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Sounds like `data` might not be in an `async` function?

Comment: data isn't a function,  it's supposed to hold the text content of the response, and i tried both executing it from the console as well as from within a script file in the html page, same problem, works on chrome but not on firefox

Comment: Why are you doing an await response.text() btw?

Comment: @AakashVerma because `Response.text()` returns a Promise?

Comment: I didn't say `data` is a function (obviously it's not), I said that it wasn't *in* an `async` function  - can you post the full code so we have a [MCVE] to figure out?

Comment: Oh, alright. This is fetch, I forgot.

Comment: Please try to provide an [MCVE]. You can use StackSnippets (`[<>]` icon) to include such an example inside your question. As it stands we miss a lot of context to be able to see what is the problem. [This example also fails in Chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/obm4kn86/)

Comment: So from the console... Now, which version of FF? my 65 beta channel does also wraps console context in an `async` function (so still no repro for me).

Answer (score 5):

In main either put your below code in self executing async function or use .then.

```
let data = await get(am_url);
```

should be changed to

```
(async()=>{ let data = await get(am_url) })()
```

or

```
get(am_url).then( data => ....)
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why one browser accepts it while the other doesn't

Comment: i tried the .then  first but it didn't work that's when i started experimenting with different things and ended up with the code above, when i use the .then notation, sometimes i get the data as null, which means it didn't wait for the response

Comment: the async get function would internally pause execution when await is encountered. After the execution is finishes it will pass the data to main .then..  You can also add .catch after .then function to check if the promise is returned as Rejected

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, `await` only works **inside** `async` functions. Normally you can't use `await` like that, but you have to create an `async` function first or use `.then()` instead of `await`.

However there are 2 things to be aware of:

1. The console supports `await` outside an `async` function just to simplify your life. [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#await) did it first, then [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1414726) more recently. Your example now works in both browsers.
2. In a future version of ECMAScript, you will be able to use `await` outside `async` functions, it's called ["top-level `await`"](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await), so that code will soon work everywhere (in a `type="module"` context)

Comment: This explains much more what's failing than the most voted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In 2018 when this question was asked, most JavaScript consoles did not await at the top level.

At that time, Google Chrome Developer Tools console was the exception. They added the feature in [late 2017 in Chrome 62](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#await)

This is why, in the Firefox version you used when you asked this question, you have to resolve the promise, for example with then/catch.

If you update to a current Firefox, such as version 72 (early 2020), the code in your question will work. As [fregante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288906/fregante) pointed out in a comment, in 2019, Firefox upgraded their console to support top level await.

Comment: Firefox also added support for it in the console last year https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1414726